# Why does setRedirect(false) on a public page(Site) is not working?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, pagereference, redirect

```
public EventsController(){
        eventId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
```

I got this first vf page button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!BookerInformation}" value="PROCEED" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-register"/>
```

apex code:

```
public PageReference BookerInformation(){

            PageReference pgr = new PageReference('/apex/bookerinformation?id=' + eventId); 
            pgr.setRedirect(false);
            return pgr;
        }
```

2nd vf page button;

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!BookingConfirmation}" value="PROCEED" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-proceed"/>
```

apex code:

```
public PageReference BookingConfirmation() {

        PageReference pagr= new PageReference('/apex/bookingconfirmation?id=' + eventId); 
        pgr.setRedirect(false);
        return pgr;
       }
```

This scenario is on the public page(Sites). When I click the button on the 1st page it goes to other page while the parameter was not changed. The problem is when I click the button on the 2nd page it will go to 3rd page but the parameters are changed. Why does this happen? I already set the redirect to false.

But when we try this on the visualforce page setRedirect(false) is working. Only in the public page(Site) its not working. Anyone who encounter like this? Is there any possible solution?

Comment: View state - fields on the controller - are only preserved for requests to pages that use the same controller (including requests back to the same page). Is that what you are seeing?